# Using Ionic 3 FCM plugin to navigate to specific page and return to homepage even when app is closed

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

Currently I am using the fcm plugin to send push notifications to my ionic 3 app. I am also able to push and view specific pages when the notifications are tapped with the ability to return to the homepage while the app is in the background.

```
    fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
       if(data.wasTapped){
          if(data.type == "created"){
            this.nav.push('PostsolutionPage', {key : data.IssueID});
          }
        } else {
          if(data.type == "created"){
            //show Toast
          }
        }
    });
```

However if I tap a notification while the app isn't in the background. The page I want to load appears However I cannot return to the homepage(RootPage) again. Is there any way to resolve this?

(I don't know whether this is required but I set my Rootpage to a loginpage or a homepage by subscribing to a firebase auth instance and navigating accordingly)

Comment: Can't you add a button and use setRoot() to go to homepage?

Comment: I could but i thought of going for that as a last resort. I have at least 4 types of notifications and each going to a different page